# Prove that if a finite group $G$ is soluble and has more than one $17$-Sylow subgroup, then it has more than $100$ $17$-Sylow subgroups.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Prove that if a finite group $G$ is soluble and has more than one $17$-Sylow subgroup, then it has more than $100$ $17$-Sylow subgroups.

My main reason for asking: Do people find this easy or hard?

There is a somewhat obscure theorem that yields a one-sentence proof, but I'm not sure whether there is an easy way without using that theorem.

I'd be interested in an elementary proof, if there is one.

NEW: Actually, I just thought of a not-too-hard proof that doesn't use that theorem, but it does use chief series.  So I guess my question amounts to whether there is any reasonable way of proving this without using chief series.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $G$ be a counterexample of smallest order, let $P \in {\rm Syl}_{17}(G)$, and let $N$ be a minimal normal subgroup of $G$.

Then, since $G$ is solvable, $N$ is abelian and, since its Sylow subgroups are normal in $G$, $N$ must be a $p$-group for some prime $p$, and hence $|N| = p^k$ for some $k>0$.

If $G/N$ has more than $100$ Sylow $17$-subgroups then so does $G$ so, since $G$ is a minimal counterexample, $G/N$ has a unique Sylow $17$-subgroup. So $PN/N \unlhd G/N$ and hence $PN \unlhd G$.

Now $P$ cannot be the unique Sylow $17$-subgroup of $PN$ or else it would be normal in $G$, and the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $PN$ must divide $p^k$ and be equal to $1 \bmod 17$

The smallest number satisfying those conditions is $103$.

Comment: Thanks....I was thinking of bumping any $17^n$ chief factor down the chief series until it encountered a suitable chief factor (e.g., of size 103) that would impede its progress.  Your proof is the same principle but much simpler conceptually.